# Plot with Through[{f,g}[x]]... A bug or a misuse of Through[]?

Tags: plotting

I was expecting

```
Plot[{Sin[x], Cos[x]}, {x, -1, 1}, PlotLabels -> Automatic]
```

and

```
Plot[Through[{Sin, Cos}[x]], {x, -1, 1}, PlotLabels -> Automatic]
```

to give the same result, as

```
Through[{Sin, Cos}[x]]
```

gives

> `{Sin[x], Cos[x]}`

However I get this two different plots:

[image: plot 1]
[image: plot 2]

Is it a bug or do I misunderstand something? (maybe HoldAll Plot[] attribute does not mix well with Through[])

(I am running under Linux with MMA version 11.2.0 for Linux x86 (64-bit) (September 11, 2017))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with `Evaluate`

```
Plot[Through[{Sin, Cos}[x]] // Evaluate, {x, -1, 1},PlotLabels -> Automatic]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, that fixes the problem!